# Does DirectXMath work on OSX and Linux with OpenGL?

Tags: directxmath

Is the DirectXMath library cross platform?  Is it possible to use it with OpenGL and/or on OSX  and Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectXMath primarily relies on the Visual Studio compiler intrinsics support. As a header in the Windows 8.x SDK, it officially only supports Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio 2013, and Windows Vista or later. It only has a single Win32 API dependency (IsProcessorFeaturePresent), even that is optional.

It is technically possible to use it for Windows XP, but there's no official SDK configuration that would provide it in the headers that are supported on Windows XP.

There's no official support for other compilers, but it would probably work with the Intel compiler.

Otherwise DirectXMath is not actually tied to Direct3D in particular, so you could use it with OpenGL or whatever.

The main issue is going to be that the DirectXMath library is available in the Windows 8.x SDK, the Windows Phone 8.x SDK, the Xbox One XDK, and Xbox One ADK. You'd have to look at those EULAs--I'm not a lawyer and I cannot provide legal advice.